# Creating platform on automating supply chain functions with Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I would like to know is Memgraph a good option to create platform on automating supply chain functions. Something like Procure-to-Pay as all documents within the process has highly connected data like purchase order number which ties up with all other document.

Answer (score 0):

The use case seems very suited to be represented and handled as a graph. All the connections between documents, stakeholders and supply chain links can be easily modeled as a graph. It would also be very easy and computationally efficient to find connections to other documents in the network.
You can also use some built-in features to help automate the process. For example, triggers and query modules:

• Triggers can be used to define events on which a procedure will be triggered. For example, if you need to notify a person about a document once it’s created and added to the database, you can create a trigger that will fire every time a specific document is created and send a notification (email, push notification, etc.) to the person responsible for it or all users who are connected to the document in the database.

• Query modules can be used to create custom procedures and you can implement them in Python, C/C++ and Rust. For example, you can create the aforementioned notification procedure using query modules. It could be a simple Python script that sends an email to the specified email address.
Also, depending on the architecture of your system, if you are using a message broker like Apache Kafka, you can connect it directly to Memgraph and ingest the data instead of having to implement an intermediary service that would instead connect to the database.
I hope that this info can be of help to you. Feel free to ping me if you have any further questions or you need more info